# Работа с бинарными файлами в C

Tags: c

Работа программы заключается в следующем: в бинарный файл пишется блоками инфа о студентах. При каждой операции добавления проверяется на наличие свободных мест последний считанный из файла блок. Если мест не осталось, то создается новый. Проблема заключается в следующем: при создании блока внутри функции добавления и записи его, в файле наблюдаются многочисленные буквы "М", то есть, как будто созданный блок остался неинициализированным, хотя отладчик говорит об обратном:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема решается, если создать глобальную переменную типа "блок", но, мне кажется, это не лучший выход из данной ситуации. Ниже прилагаю код метода добавления студента в файл:

```
void AddStudent(Student tempStudent)
{
    filePointer = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb+");

    if (fileSize == SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        numberOfBlocks++;
    }

    int pastePosition = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE;
            i++) //Находим позицию в блоке для добавления студента
    {
        if (buffer.students[i].id == 0)
        {
            pastePosition = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pastePosition !=
            -1)        //Если есть место в блоке, вставляем запись
    {
        buffer.students[pastePosition].id = tempStudent.id;
        strcpy(buffer.students[pastePosition].surname, tempStudent.surname);
        strcpy(buffer.students[pastePosition].name, tempStudent.name);
        strcpy(buffer.students[pastePosition].patronymic,
               tempStudent.patronymic);
        buffer.students[pastePosition].groupNumber = tempStudent.groupNumber;

        for (int i = pastePosition + 1; i < BLOCK_SIZE;
                i++)//Заполняем нулями остальные места в блоке
        {
            buffer.students[i].id = 0;
            strcpy(buffer.students[i].surname, "");
            strcpy(buffer.students[i].name, "");
            strcpy(buffer.students[i].patronymic, "");
            buffer.students[i].groupNumber = 0;
        }

        fseek(filePointer, SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE * numberOfBlocks , SEEK_SET);
        cout << ftell(filePointer);
        system("pause");
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(DataBlock), 1, filePointer);
    }
    else
    {
        DataBlock tempBlock;                //Иначе создаём новую
        tempBlock.students[0].id = tempStudent.id;
        strcpy(tempBlock.students[0].surname, tempStudent.surname);
        strcpy(tempBlock.students[0].name, tempStudent.name);
        strcpy(tempBlock.students[0].patronymic, tempStudent.patronymic);
        tempBlock.students[0].groupNumber = tempStudent.groupNumber;

        for (int i = 1; i < BLOCK_SIZE;
                i++) //Заполняем нулями остальные места в блоке
        {
            tempBlock.students[i].id = 0;
            strcpy(tempBlock.students[i].surname, "");
            strcpy(tempBlock.students[i].name, "");
            strcpy(tempBlock.students[i].patronymic, "");
            tempBlock.students[i].groupNumber = 0;
        }

        numberOfBlocks++;
        fseek(filePointer, SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE * numberOfBlocks, SEEK_SET);
        cout << ftell(filePointer);
        system("pause");
        fwrite(&tempBlock, sizeof(DataBlock), 1, filePointer);
    }

    fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(filePointer);
    fclose(filePointer);
}
```

Comment: В чем вопрос если используя глобальную переменную вы решили проблему.

Comment: Локальная переменная, мусор, при записи буфер заполняется не полностью - типа, поле описано как char[100], а записывается только 20 символов... Нет?

Comment: Смущает только  `cout << ftell(filePointer);`

Comment: когда Вы создаете локальную переменную, то она не обнуляется автоматом. А вот глобальные - обнуляются. Обнуляйте ручками (memset к примеру, но аккуратно). И в целом, подобное - большая дыра в безопасности, но Вам думаю это пока не страшно.

Comment: @KoVadim Так я вроде обнуляю ее в цикле for, не? Или обнуляются только массивы внутри блока?

Comment: Вы не предоставили определение DataBlock. Но побуду КО.  Код вида `strcpy(tempBlock.students[i].surname, "");` на самом деле просто записывает один ноль в самый первый байт, а остальное не трогает.